# Where can I find a gem for the creation of test items?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

is there a *gem* for Ruby on Rails to create *"test questions"*?

[1]: http://rubygems.org/ did not help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

another tool is.

http://www.ruby-toolbox.com you can find all what you need for your rails application like gems and plugins with categories